# Typescript: Is it possible to setState for only one key in exported type?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, setstate

I decided to try out and learn Typescript in my React App and I got into first error I can't figure out or find the answer for it.

**Is it possible to access only one specific key in exported type and change its value?**

So I am exporting my type like this:

```
export type MyFirstTestType = {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    price: number;
    object1: {
        name: string;
        price: number;
},
    object2: {
        name: string;
        price: number;
},
```

And then I am getting the values from my external API

```
const getTestItems = async (): Promise<MyFirstTestType[]> =>
    await (await fetch('apiEndpoint')).json();
```

In classic JS I would just create new state for price

```
 const [itemPrice, setItemPrice] = React.useState(data.price)
```

and then easily update state with `onClick` function. Is is possible to achieve something like this with TypeScript? So I can update only the **price** from `MyFirstTestType`?

I tried similar thing:

```
const [price, setPrice] = React.useState<MyFirstTestType>({price: 100});
```

But this throw error of -> Type *'{ price: number; }' is missing the rest of the properties in `MyFirstTestType`* (id, name,...)

Comment: If your actual state has only some properties of your type you can use `React.useState<Partial<CartItemType>>`

Comment: Thanks @YuryTarabanko, but this throws another error: `'Partial' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here.`

Comment: If you want the state to be of type `{price: number}` than use that as your type. Using another type, that shares nearly nothing with your intended type just couples the code unnecessarly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off you should use interface instead of type

You can use another type for your setState type that extends the origin type

```
export interface MyFirstTestType {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  price: number;
  object1: {
    name: string;
    price: number;
  };
  object2: {
    name: string;
    price: number;
  };
}
export interface MyFirstTestTypeState extends Partial<MyFirstTestType> {
  name?: string;
  price: number;
  object1?: {
    name: string;
    price: number;
  };
  object2?: {
    name: string;
    price: number;
  };
}
```

In this case id and other would be optional only for state but for your request you can use the one that `id` and other are not optional, you can still see `MyFirstTestType` properties and use them the only difference is that you now can update any property you want

Now import it and then in your use state

```
  const [price, setPrice] = useState<MyFirstTestTypeState>({price:2});
```

Here is the sandbox example
https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-hooks-zwisw?file=/src/App.tsx:154-224

Comment: Hey @YahyaParvar, to make it work I have to put ? after every single key, but that's not suitable solution for me, since I am using it in online shop, where ID is crucial and if I put ? there, it throws me an error of undefined data.

Comment: I updated the answer, have a look and tell me the resault

Comment: Thank you! That does make sense what you updated, so basically I will just setup new value onClick with `onClick={() => {setPrice()}}`, correct?

Comment: I think you're missing a important concept in there, TypeScript is just for type checking, it does not change anything or declare objects, you can declare objects and then assign a type to it so it has the type checking feature, then you can change the object,  in summary, for manipulating objects, you will use normal JS as you did before, but to set types and use type checking features you'll end up using typescript, Consider TypeScript as a reader, you tell it this object is `Hello` type, whenever you use it, it reads what you used and throws error if it reads something unusual,nothing more.

Comment: If you use `onClick={() => {setPrice()}}` for normal JS as well, yes. if not, no

Answer (score 2):

The example in your question is misleading.

JS: `const [itemPrice, setItemPrice] = React.useState(data.price)`

TS: `const [price, setPrice] = React.useState<MyFirstTestType>({price: 100});`

In the JS example you're initializing `itemPrice` with a value from `data.price` (it's not clear where `data` come from). Note that while `setItemPrice` will update your `itemPrice` variable, it will not update the value on the `data` object as you seem to think. But in the TS example you're doing something different: you're intializing `price` with an entirely new object.

Now the point is: what kind of value is `price` going to hold?

If that will be a simple price (like in the JS example) you're type declaration is wrong, because you're declaring that value as `MyFirstTestType`.

If it will indeed hold a value of type `MyFirstTestType` then you must certainly pass a valid `MyFirstTestType` instance as initial value (or `undefined`). And how a valid `MyFirstTestType` instance looks like, depends on your type declaration.

But note that either in JS or in TS you should treat your state as immutable: the only difference here is type checking.